# Safe to delete the last version of SVN repo?

Tags: svn

I have a SVN repo with youngest revision 1001, I did a commit and now the version is 1002.

But 1002 is wrong. instead of re-commit a new revision (which is too large and to complex to do it once again), I just want to revert the SVN repo back to 1001.

I deleted "svn.repo/db/1/1002", and changed "svn.repo/db/current" back to 1001. Then svn info shows the lastest version is 1001. Great!

But I'm wondering is this wrong/problematic ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's wrong. You should NEVER modify the repository by hand. The files in the repository are NOT meant to be editable by hand. You may very well have just caused irreversible harm to your repository.

The correct method is to commit a new version to undo all the changes. But you certainly don't need to do it by hand. You just need to do a "reverse merge" of that revision into a working copy at HEAD, and then commit that. If you use a GUI client this can be even easier. TortoiseSVN for example includes a "revert changes from this revision" command in the context menu when you right-click any revision in the "show log" dialog. This command will do the reverse merge for you, undoing all changes from the selected revision in your working copy. When done, you just commit.